# camera_pose_calibration not working in fuerte

Tags: calibration, asus-xtion-pro-live, camera-pose-calibration, webcam, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I would like to extrinsically calibrate a webcam and a asus xtion pro live sensor.
Therefore I would like to use the camera_pose_calibration. Everything is intrinsically calibrated and I get the two images. But the checkerboard detector is not working.

while launchup the following message pops up:

```
can't locate node [image_cb_detector_action_old] in package [image_cb_detector]
```

My try to just copy the image_cb_detector_action to image_detector_action_old resultet in a tracked checkerboard but no working calibration.

```
[capture_exec-14] process has died [pid 9092, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/camera_pose/camera_pose_calibration/src/camera_pose_calibration/multicam_capture_exec.py panda_cam camera/rgb request_interval:=interval_filtered __name:=capture_exec __log:=/home/pclinux/.ros/log/b9d2f746-5150-11e2-a6a7-b8ac6f40a936/capture_exec-14.log].
log file: /home/pclinux/.ros/log/b9d2f746-5150-11e2-a6a7-b8ac6f40a936/capture_exec-14*.log
```

Is there another working solution for extrinsic calibration for two sensors? (doesn't need to be ROS) I would appreciate any suggestion.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51180/camera_pose_calibration-not-working-in-fuerte/) by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 447 on 2012-12-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on 2014-01-08**:
***opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/camera_pose/camera_pose_calibration/src/camera_pose_calibration/multicam_capture_exec.py*** have you figured out why this occurs?  I've had both of these occur, as well as others: http://answers.ros.org/question/115111/errors-in-camera_pose_calibration-launch-for-3-kinects/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I applied some fixes I found [here](https://github.com/jbohren-forks/camera_pose/commit/84b6a9a0892d1f1acce39c7b178e75128de1f491), although with these fixes I have not been able to get it to work yet. I am not sure if these fixes are still required or not (some of missing tabs were already removed in my version).

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on 2013-01-06**:
I used your repository and it worked without a problem. Did you use a good ir lighting source?

**Comment by [CHz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4559/chz/) on 2013-03-31**:
Did you manage this lightning problem ? I always see black on ir image.